# Loading listView in new activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a bit of a trouble loading contents to a fresh listView. If i use setContentView, it displays an empty list and if i try changing my Intent the app crashes. Please what am I doing wrong. The main Activity class is:

```
ListView lv;
Context context;

private int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.phones_and_tablets,R.drawable.home_and_kitchen_appliances,
        R.drawable.beauty_health_and_personal_care,R.drawable.fashion,R.drawable.subscriptions,
        R.drawable.electronics,R.drawable.windows_logo,R.drawable.music_and_movies,
        R.drawable.baby_kids_and_toys,R.drawable.sports,R.drawable.books_and_stationery,
        R.drawable.fastfood_and_eatery};
private String [] prgmNameList={"Phones & Tablets","Home & Kitchen","Beauty, Health & Personal Care",
        "Fashion","Subscriptions","Electronics","Computer & Accessories","Music & Movies","Baby, Kids & Toys",
        "Sports & Fitness","Books & Stationery","Fast Food, Drinks & Groceries"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this; // Instantiate context after listView's properties are set.
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new MainCustomAdapter(this, this.prgmNameList, this.prgmImages));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch( position ){
                case 0:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_fone_cats); break; }
                case 1:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_kit_cats); break; }
                case 2:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_beauty_care_cats); break; }
                case 3:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_fashion_cats); break; }
                case 4:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_telecoms_cats); break; }
                case 5:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_electronics_cats); break; }
                case 6:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_computers_cats); break; }
                case 7:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_entertainment_cats); break; }
                case 8:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_toys_cats); break; }
                case 9:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_sports_cats); break; }
                case 10:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_stationeries_cats); break; }
                case 11:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_f_food_drinks_grocery_cats); break; }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My main xml layout construct is as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:text="@string/action_companyName" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_motto"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_query"
    android:textColor="#3a94d5" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="@string/action_query2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_query2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ad" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="."
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

I built it the following custom adapter:

```
String [] category; // The category a sales-item belongs to
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public MainCustomAdapter(MainActivity currentActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    context = currentActivity;
    category = prgmNameList;
    imageId = prgmImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return category.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder{ // Set an object to hold category items for each position in the list
    TextView txt;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programlist, null);
    holder.txt=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.txt.setText(category[position]); // Hold the name of the selected category
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]); // Hold the icon of the selected category
    return rowView;
}
```

programlist layout was built as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

I built activity_fone_cats thus:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:text="@string/action_companyName" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_motto"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_query"
    android:textColor="#3a94d5" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="@string/action_query2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_query2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ad" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="."
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

Please how do I ensure that the items in the list are displayed upon clicking on a listItem in main activity and how do I stop the app from crashing if I wanted to use changing of Intents, instead of switching contentViews?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception, "my app crashes" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: post your Log message

Comment: Purpose of using setContentView(...) within onItemClickListener(...) method?

Comment: @Egor, please I'm a newbie around Android programming. My AVD is not working. How do I obtain fitting stack trace?

Comment: @Srinivasan, true. But, when I use setContentView(...), I seem to have trouble displaying the items for the next content view. If the app is loaded, the main view displays with the full loaded list. When user clicks on an item in the list, it loads everything on the next contentView but, will not display the contents in the new view.

Comment: Everything is fine except the  prgmNameList array.It contains 14 elements whereas your prgmImages has 12 elements.Please adjust the array properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        lv.setAdapter(new MainCustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList, prgmImages));

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) setContentView(R.layout.activity_fone_cats);
                else if (position == 1) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(view.getContext(),HomeKitchenCatsActivity.class), 0);
                    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_kit_cats);
                }
                else if (position == 2) setContentView(R.layout.activity_beauty_care_cats);
                else if (position == 3) setContentView(R.layout.activity_fashion_cats);
                else if (position == 4) setContentView(R.layout.activity_telecoms_cats);
                else if (position == 5) setContentView(R.layout.activity_electronics_cats);
                else if (position == 6) setContentView(R.layout.activity_computers_cats);
                else if (position == 7) setContentView(R.layout.activity_entertainment_cats);
                else if (position == 8) setContentView(R.layout.activity_toys_cats);
                else if (position == 9) setContentView(R.layout.activity_sports_cats);
                else if (position == 10) setContentView(R.layout.activity_stationeries_cats);
                else if (position == 11) setContentView(R.layout.activity_f_food_drinks_grocery_cats);
            }
            });
```

Comment: Hi @Ankita, with your answer always provide some explanation, answers with only code  is not consider good enough.

Comment: I tried that before #Ankita but, when I do that, the items on the list in the next view disappears. That's why I was seeking to change intent.

Comment: @Ankita, I edited the code to include the content view layout I am trying to switch to. My problem is that the list items do not display in its list in activity_fone_cats (for example). It opens the view, loads every other content but leaves the list space empty without display content. I would have wanted some other items to be displayed in the list that is displayed in it content's view.

Comment: Or is it that it is not possible to change view to another view that displays a list? That seems to be the case... If you change views, lists no longer are displayable!

Answer (score 0):

@aburimegregory yes you have got the answer now. OnItem click you want to bind new layout with your activity.

```
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new MainCustomAdapter(this, this.prgmNameList, this.prgmImages));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch( position ){
                    case 0:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_fone_cats); break; }
                    case 1:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_kit_cats); break; }
                    case 2:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_beauty_care_cats); break; }
                    case 3:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_fashion_cats); break; }
                    case 4:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_telecoms_cats); break; }
                    case 5:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_electronics_cats); break; }
                    case 6:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_computers_cats); break; }
                    case 7:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_entertainment_cats); break; }
                    case 8:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_toys_cats); break; }
                    case 9:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_sports_cats); break; }
                    case 10:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_stationeries_cats); break; }
                    case 11:  { setContentView(R.layout.activity_f_food_drinks_grocery_cats); break; }
                }

               lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
               lv.setAdapter(new MainCustomAdapter(this, this.prgmNameList, this.prgmImages));
            }
        });
```

After binding new layout, you need to find the listview and set the adapter to load the list of items in the new ContentView.

Same thing you need to do for all other items in the new layout.(Find the view and set the value after binding new layout)

Note:I am not sure about your project requirment.Your way of approaching the listview may be inappropriate. Spend some more time to learn listview and its functionality and then start implement. All the best.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. Pls I need closer assistance. I've been on this stage for over a month due to system crash and its getting quite frustrating now cos this happens to be a very important project work. I simply dont know how to get about this. All i wanted was, when user clicks on an item in a list, app displays a new content view that is made up of another list with a fresh set of items. Pls can anyone help?

Comment: @aburimegregory Yes i can understand. one thing keep in your mind. Now you are showing an .xml file initially with some views and listview, all are having id, you may be finding the view and added click listeners or adapters to it. When you change the xml of the activity(views are unbinded with activity) you cannot use the ids of previous xml and should not set any values to the previous xml file views ,when you click the list item, you are binding new xml with your current activity, so you need to find all the views and add listeners and adaters as like new activity with views